# Close(st) Binary Boxes

Tags: code-golf, number, integer, binary

### Challenge:

Given a list of non-negative integers, determine by how much you should increase each item to create the closest binary box with the resulting integer-list.

**What is a binary box?**

A binary box is where the first and last rows consists of `1`-bits; the first and last columns consist of `1`-bits; and everything else (if applicable) consists of `0`-bits. Some examples of binary boxes, with their corresponding integer-list below it:

```
                                             111
              1111                           101                           1111111
      111     1001        11      11111      101                           1000001
11    101     1001        11      10001      101         1111111           1000001
11    111     1111        11      11111      111         1111111   1   11  1111111

[3,3] [7,5,7] [15,9,9,15] [3,3,3] [31,17,31] [7,5,5,5,7] [255,255] [1] [3] [127,65,65,127]
```

**Example I/O:**

- If the input is `[0,2]`, the output would be `[3,1]`, because `[3,3]` is the closest binary box to reach by increasing numbers: `[0+3,2+1]`.
- If the input is `[3,4,1]`, the output would be `[4,1,6]`, because `[7,5,7]` is the closest binary box to reach by increasing numbers: `[3+4,4+1,1+6]`.
- If the input is `[2]`, the output would be `[1]`, because `[3]` is the closest binary box to reach by increasing numbers: `[2+1]`.

### Challenge rules:

- The goal is to find the closest binary box. If the input is `[1,2,3]` the output should be `[2,1,0]`; so `[62,31,60]` wouldn't be allowed as output, even though [it does form a binary box](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fO@nQ7v//ow11jHSMY7mizYCUoY6ZQSwA) as well.
- I/O can be taken in any reasonable format. Can be a list/array/stream of integers; read one by one from STDIN; etc. **You are not allowed to take the input-integers as binary-strings.**
- The input-integers are guaranteed to be non-negative; and the output-integers may not be negative.
- If the input is already a binary-box of itself, you can choose to output a corresponding list of 0s, or the result for the next binary-box in line. I.e. input `[3,3,3]` may result in both `[0,0,0]` or `[4,2,4]`.

The first/last rows of the binary-boxes with binary `111...111` form the OEIS sequences [A000042](http://oeis.org/A000042) (literal) and [A000225](http://oeis.org/A000225): \$a(n)=2^n-1\$ (as base-10 integers).
The middle rows of the binary-boxes with binary `100...001` form the OEIS sequences [A000533](http://oeis.org/A000533) (literal) and [A083318](http://oeis.org/A083318): \$a(n)=2^n+1\$ (as base-10 integers).

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

```
Input:  [0,2]
Output: [3,1]

Input:  [3,4,1]
Output: [4,1,6]

Input:  [2]
Output: [1]

Input:  [3,3,3]
Output: [0,0,0] OR [4,2,4]

Input:  [1,27,40]
Output: [62,6,23]

Input:  [7,20,6,44,14]
Output: [120,45,59,21,113]

Input:  [7,20,6,33,14]
Output: [56,13,27,0,49]

Input:  [7,2,6,3,14]
Output: [8,7,3,6,1]

Input:  [1,0,1]
Output: [0,1,0]

Input:  [1,2,3]
Output: [2,1,0]

Input:  [0]
Output: [1]

Input:  [6,6,6]
Output: [9,3,9]
```

Comment: By what metric is the distance between two boxes calculated? (when you say the closest binary box)

Comment: @CommandMaster Not sure if it's relevant? I guess you mean to ask whether it's by base-10 integers or the binary-bits? The idea is by base-10 integers, but since we're only allowing increasing the numbers (or keeping them the same by increasing with 0) and never decreasing, it wouldn't matter whether the metric is by base-10 integers or the binary itself, unless I'm missing something? Could you give an example where your question would give different results based on the metric used? Or am I misunderstanding your question completely?

Comment: By "You are not allowed to take the input-integers as binary", did you mean "binary string representation of the number"? (normally numbers are stored internally in binary format anyway)

Comment: @user202729 Yes, that was indeed what I meant. I'll edit it a bit. How it's stored internally doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Razetime You can only increase, not decrease.

Comment: So the correct output for `[6, 6, 6]` is `[9, 3, 9]`? What's the correct output for `[0]`?

Comment: @Neil Yep, that is indeed correct. And `[0]` would result in `[1]`. I've added both as test cases.

Comment: I think you should still specify the metric. I guess your metric is "the sum of the output list should be minimal", but the word "closest" usually means "the sum of the **squares** is minimal", so it is worth explicitly writing what the metric is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>25</s> <s>21</s> 18 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

```
[NoD<Id¦¦s.ø~I-Wd#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2i/fxcYz5dCyQ8uK9Q7vqPPUDU9RBgob65joGMYCAA) or [Try all cases!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BN09BKdov38XGM@XQskPLivUO76jz1A1PUVZSsFNIzk9J1UtMSuUqz8jMSVUoSk1MUcjM40rJ51JQ0M8vKNHPL05MykyFUnDlCjY2NgoqYIV5qf//RxvoGMVyRRvrmOgYAmkIGwiBtKGOkbmOiQGQZa5jZKBjpmMCVGOC4Bobw7kgHoRjqGMANgioGWQIAA)

**Commented**:

```python
[                    # infinite loop, for N=0,1, ...
 No                  # push 2**N
   D                 # duplicate this value
    <                # decrement
     Id              # push a list of 1's in the same length as the input
       ¦¦            # remove the first 2 elements
         s           # swap to 2**N-1
          .ø         # surround the list of 1's to get a new list of the same length as the input
                     #  => [2**N-1, 1, ..., 1, 2**N-1]
            ~        # bitwise OR with 2**N, this is now the binary grid of width N+1
                     #  => [2**n|2**N-1, 2**N|1, ..., 2**N|1, 2**N|2**N-1]
             I-      # subtract the input list element-wise from the binary grid
               W     # take the minimum without popping the list
                d    # if this is non-negative
                 #   # break the infinite loop and implicitly print the list
```

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>47 46</s></sup> 48 bytes

```apl
{x←0⋄⍵{x≡|x⊢←⍺-⍨⊥(1@1)∘⌽∘⍉⍣4⊢0×⍵:x⋄⍺∇⍵⍪0}⊤⍵+~×⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v7riUdsEg0fdLY96twLZnQtrKh51LQKKPerdpfuod8WjrqUahg6Gmo86Zjzq2Qsiezsf9S42ASoyODwdqMmqAqx516OOdiDvUe8qg9pHXUuATO06sHzt/zSwaX2Pupof9a551Lvl0HrjR20TH/VNDQ5yBpIhHp7B/9OBaqqBHK9gfz@FNJBBXYuBXKCounotF1e6goGCEZA0VjBRMATSOiCOjgFYBAiBtKGCkbmCCUjEXMHIQMFMwQSo0gTBNTaGc0E8CMcQaKwhRLOCMQA)

A dfn which takes a vector as its right argument.

Outputs a list of 0's if the input is already a binary-box.

+2 bytes after a fix.(Thanks, Arnauld)

### Explanation

```apl
{x←0⋄⍵{x≡|x⊢←⍺-⍨⊥(1@1)∘⌽∘⍉⍣4⊢0×⍵:x⋄⍺∇⍵⍪0}⊤⍵+~×⍵}
 x←0                                             set var x to 0(required for extended)
      {x≡|x⊢←⍺-⍨⊥(1@1)∘⌽∘⍉⍣4⊢0×⍵:x⋄⍺∇⍵⍪0}        call the following recursive function with
                                          ⍵+~×⍵  add !(signum(input)) to itself
                                                 (special casing for [0])
                                         ⊤       converted to binary matrix
     ⍵                                           and the input list as right arg
                                :                If:
                             0×⍵                 the matrix converted to zeroes
                 (1@1)∘⌽∘⍉⍣4⊢                    with 1s added on each side
                ⊥                                convert from binary
             ⍺-⍨                                 subtract from the input
          x⊢←                                    assign to x
       x≡|                                       if x matches its absolute value
                                 x               then return x
                                  ⋄⍺∇⍵⍪0         otherwise add a row of zeroes, and try again
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>72</s>  71 bytes

Outputs a list of 0's if the input is already a binary-box.

```javascript
a=>(g=k=>/-/.test(b=a.map((v,i)=>(i/a[i+1]?k^k/2|1:k)-v))?g(k-~k):b)(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBBboMwELz3FRxtZcGsbUyJRPKESr0iV3JSgqjTEAXEqerX6XJIRIFK9d5mZ8az8@F61x5v9bULL817OZzyweU7VuU@34lQRF3ZduyQu@jTXRnroea0rYUr6g3avX/zQn7h1vOw53xfMR9@e749cIZ8ODaXtjmX0bmp2IkVMUgb3B/ngRBBoQDt04ynQBP6m0cImAVz4vdgrvnRzPxioLHBy@toLUEvRAgyBR3bqchIMCDVgpuCjGmjKaS29xgE6QSSDCQC4p8ipSaixACq8WPSZmuKUTDyH5GeISXErLSIZIKLqwldO3XRj1xlxv/q21AeM/PLKGVmhx8)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                   // a[] = input array
(g = k =>              // g is a recursive function taking a bit mask k
                       // of the form (2 ** n) - 1
  /-/.test(            // test whether there is a minus side in the ...
    b = a.map(         //   ... array b[] defined as the result of this map()
      (v, i) =>        //   for each value v at position i in a[]:
      ( i / a[i + 1] ? //     if this is neither the first nor the last item
                       //     (i.e. i is not equal to 0 and a[i + 1] is defined):
          k ^ k / 2    //       use the vertical borders
          | 1          //       e.g. (0b111111 XOR (0b111111 >> 1)) OR 1 = 0b100001
        :              //     else:
          k            //       use the horizontal border (i.e. the full bit mask k)
      ) - v            //     subtract v
    )                  //   end of map()
  )                    // end of test()
  ?                    // if there's a minus sign:
    g(k - ~k)          //   try again with 2 * k + 1
  :                    // else:
    b                  //   success: return b[]
)(1)                   // initial call to g with k = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 95 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,n=1:(b:=[x-y for x,y in zip(([n|n-1]+[n|1]*(len(s)-2))*2,s)])*(min(b)>=0)or f(s,n*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCoJQEEX3fcXsnLER3ntKhqQ/Ii6UeiToU9SFVn67TQnFLO49MPf0y3TvXHjuh22zaVO21bWEkV2qE6ySNJ@DBWw3wMwL1A4edY@Yu5cLdHGU1IWPzc3hSIEh8g2PVJCPbe2woixVJFOL4vMNbV/Px5IrNgXnIUesJfcuJ6nZxBwpaTEbxSeO5Cf6Yxj@8EM7aFZfkYxFkhwA@qF2E1rvOU4DzpRc9HmFIIOnFVo92t4)

**Commented**:

```python
f=lambda s,n=1:           # f is a recursive function taking two arguments:
                          # a list of integers: s, and the current power of 2: n
                          # it tries all binary boxes with the correct number of rows
                          # until it finds one where all row numbers are >= the values in s

     (b:= ... )           # construct a list of differences between row numbers and s
   * (min(b)>=0)          # if there is no negative value in this list, return it
  or f(s,n*2)             # otherwise try the next power of 2
                 
[x-y for x,y in zip(...,s)])] # take the differences of each pair of row numbers and integers in s

 [n|n-1]                  # the first and last row are equal to n|n-1;
                          # example: n=8, n|n-1 = 8|7 = 0b1000|0b0111 = 0b1111 = 15
+[n|1]*(len(s)-2)         # the middle rows are n|1
                          # example: n=8, n|1 = 8|1 = 0b1000|0b0001 = 0b1001 = 9
 (...)*2                  # repeat this list twice to get the first row twice,
                          # zip will ignore all extra elements
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
≔¹ζ≔⁻¹θηＷ‹⌊η⁰«≦⊗ζ≔Ｅθ⁻⎇﹪λ⊖Ｌθ⊕ζ⊖⊗ζκη»Ｉη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4/C8IwEMXn9lNkvEAEXVw6iV0ECw5upUNsgwmmSZs/ihU/e0xpROSme@/d717LqWk1lSHsrBVXBRuCJlzkaauE8nbWRkwQj/qDC8kQHJm1syl63wOP3hpj9Mqzig7pstT@Ilm30LIvjg4wErRQz8woap5Q6c5LDZKgkrWG9Uw51sUP6uo4jDjCD@qnT/g/l/5EfU7ecOr5zk9GKAd7al0siIsQ6npL4jRNWN3lBw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: I tried directly calculating the correct box size, but there were too many edge cases.

```
≔¹ζ
```

Start with a box of width 1.

```
≔⁻¹θη
```

See whether this box can hold the input.

```
Ｗ‹⌊η⁰«
```

Repeat until a large enough box is found.

```
≦⊗ζ
```

Increase the size of the box.

```
≔Ｅθ⁻⎇﹪λ⊖Ｌθ⊕ζ⊖⊗ζκη
```

Calculate the box and subtract the original input.

```
»Ｉη
```

Output the final increments.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3.8+, 91 bytes

```python
f=lambda b,n=1:f(b,n*2)if min(u:=r_[(t:=2*n-1),b[2:]*0+n|1,t]-b)<0else u
from numpy import*
```

The parameter `b` must be a numpy array of integers.

Therefore, no try it online.

Recurse with `n` take values `1, 2, 4, 8,...`, and construct the array

```python
r_[
(t:=2*n-1),  #first line
b[2:]*0+n|1, #middle lines, all values are n|1, length=len(b[2:])
t            #last line, same as first line
]
```

being the binary boxes, then return the first one that is no smaller than `b`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Numpy is simply not installed on TIO. Do you know about one?

Comment: Ah ok. And no, I don't know too many online compilers. Only TIO and ideone for languages in general. In that case, could you perhaps add a screenshot as verification? :)

Comment: You can save a few bytes by starting with `n=1` and doubling `n` on each recursive call.

Comment: @ovs Good idea.

Comment: You could save 1 by writing out ```2*n-1``` for ```t```.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>25</s> <s>31</s> <s>25</s> 26 bytes

+6 for bug fix for input [1,0,1]

-6 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

+1 for bug fix for single-element lists

```
d¸∞εoIg<и¨>y>o<.ø}«.ΔI@P}α
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9vc2FiaWX//2TCuOKIns61b0lnPNC4wqg@eT5vPC7DuH3Cqy7OlElAUH3Osf//WzJd) or [Try all cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koGunoGRf6XJo5f@UQzsedcw7tzX/0Lp0mws7Dq2wq7TLt9E7vKP20Gq9c1MOrXMIqD238b/O/@hoAx2jWJ1oYx0THUMgDWEDIZA21DEy1zExALLMdYwMdMx0TIBqTBBcY2M4F8SDcAx1DMAGATWDDQFpNwNKm8XGAgA)

Comment: There is a surround builtin, so the `©ª®š` can be `.ø` for -2. Also, the `I-` can be `α` for an additional -1. And in your new 31-byte version you can remove the leading `I`.

Comment: `IgÅ1` can be `d` to get a list of 1s, so then you're back at your 25 byte-count. :) [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9vc2FiaWX//2TCuOKIns61PG9JZ8ON0Lg@eW88LsO4fcKrLs6USUBQfc6x//9bMSwwLDFd)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>181</s> <s>175</s> 166 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)
-9 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
i,j,m;f(n,l)int*n;{for(i=m=0;i<l;i++)if(m<n[i])for(j=1;(j*=2)<(m=n[i]););for(i=0,m-2&&(j/=2);++i<l-1;)n[i]>j+1?j*=2:0;for(i=l;i--;)n[i]=j-n[i]+(!i|i==l-1|m<4?j-1:1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJtb4IwEP7Or@g0W1o5NoqoiaWa/Qe/ET4Yga1E6oKwZFF@u7uiE3AvWfvh2ufuubunvY3zstmchkpvtlWckGBfxmr3@Lo4KcggFynVsGVKlyMtDumuoErm0hUq2Apl20ylNA90qCJmfJnkgmYj6bGA5rKBBRNnlgu54z080OwJ3cK2MYPDBTNBi8zmS0Obu5dgTO44Z6fMHGNseqeOSkokHfPAX2YOn3Mm6tMwTlKlE7Ii3LOs952KyVuB/T4XxfqDEjyRkYbGbhNNmLAsc87XSlNGDpZFcBlEh6sonEQSMXJZBxe8GtrrGHzgXeDGi7sLcPBm4LtdaAaeC1PwMY//Az4ef8cNfINycPt9YKV@6V7RKaaY1s29Fo25isYnQdkERXumilEAk2aPz/cuofkbJJUY7wo0AVmhwTG4vNm1ZOcHdFhG0NQpcRr6Yemf3t@TtCFVuaeDwYVZt/wiKatCY5dW/Z@hsA49gdVZYIUC0Y2HVuLX6neZ0sF9TAaAQ1RFvW7aDuvTJw)

Comment: Nice answer! And taking the length as argument is allowed by default I think, so that's no problem. As for some golfs: `<=(m=n[i])-1;` can be `<(m=n[i]);` for -3; both `||` can be `|` for -2; and [`j*2-1-n[i]` can be `j*2+~n[i]`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144481/52210) for -1.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen wow thank you for everything

Comment: @ceilingcat as always, thank you! :D